# Phonegap Android setInterval on Sleep

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, setinterval

I wrote an Android application with cordova 2.9.0.
The app every 5 minutes to do an ajax request to a webservice.
To do this I use setInterval from js in this way:

```
setInterval (myFunction, 300000);
```

the problem is that when the phone is in sleep or is put to sleep by the user,
setInterval does not work anymore.

Is there a way to make it work even in sleep without using the native Java code?

thank you very much

Comment: i think noo , you can use background service ..

Comment: Ok thanks! I use a java service :)